# Angular | Always display autocomplete options

Tags: html, angular, typescript, search, autocomplete

How can I still show the Angular Material Autocomplete menu even if the input is not in focus? Are there any arguments to fill in? Or is it possible in TS or even in CSS?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `autofocus` attribute on your input, this will trigger your menu on your component initialization

```html
<input autofocus [matAutocomplete]="myAutoComplete">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  ...
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Or if you want to do it programmatically from your component class file, you can use `@ViewChild` to query the `MatAutocompleteTrigger`, and use its `openPanel()`, like this

```js
@ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) 
autocomplete!: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

And in your function call

```js
this.autocomplete.openPanel();
```

Comment: The problem with the first solution is that the user can lose focus of the input, for the second solution I tried to create a button that calls this.autocomplete.openPanel() but nothing happens when I click on the button.

Comment: @RaphaelCharpentier show your code for `this.autocomplete.openPanel()` method call

Comment: I tried this  `<button (click)='autocomplete.openPanel()'>open</button>` but nothing happens when pressing the button, the only time it works is when I put `(click)='autocomplete.openPanel()'` on the `<mat-option>` element which allows to leave the panel open even after clicking on an option, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry it must have been a bug, I restarted the server and it works perfectly!